# How does FirstAsync work?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In my everlasting quest to suck less I'm trying to understand Rx.net's `FirstAsync()` syntax. Most documentation is for the deprecated `First()`
If I understand correctly it allows me to start a stream as soon as the first element from a stream arrives.

Say I have a stream `myStream` and I want to start a stream that takes the first element and starts a stream based on that one element. In my case it would be a stream of one.
I expect it to do this:

---1-2->
---A--->

How would I go about this?

```
myStream.FirstAsync().Return(() => return "A"); // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why the other two answers are saying `.FirstAsync()` returns a `Task` (or that you should call `.Result`). It does not return a `Task`, it returns an `IObservable<TSource>`. Observables are awaitable, but they are not tasks.

To achieve your desired functionality, do the following: `myStream.FirstAsync().Select(_ => "A")`.

You can also do `myStream.Take(1).Select(_ => "A")`. The difference between this and the `FirstAsync` version, is that the `FirstAsync` version will throw an exception if `myStream` completes without any elements. `Take(1)` will complete with no error.

Comment: For my answer, I was referring to `System.Data.Entities.QueryableExtensions.FirstAsync()`. The OP didn't say exactly which `FirstAsync` he was referring to. I can't find any `FirstAsync()` method (extension or otherwise) under `System.Reactive`.

Comment: Like almost all Rx operators, it can be found in System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.

Answer (score 5):

In answer to "**How does FirstAsync work?**":

It returns a new `IObservable<T>` that contains either:

- The first item from the source stream (when it eventually produces one), followed by a complete.
- or, if the source stream completes without producing an item,
  an exception (via OnError), which you would need to handle with a `Catch` or in your `Subscribe` etc.

If you would rather a get a default value instead of an exception when the source completes without ever producing a first item, use `FirstOrDefaultAsync`